# Why wont the whole tile map show?

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm trying to create a very simple tile map system, I had issues a few weeks ago and asked here, but lately I have rewritten it and it stopped working correctly.

Please note that I'm using slick2D so if you want to reproduce this then you have to put the code in your main render loop.

Array

```
public static int[][] map = {{1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1}};
```

Tile map loop.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int I = 0;
int II = 0;
while(y <= 7){
    while( x <= 12){
        if(map[y][x] == 0){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile1.png");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        if(map[y][x] == 1){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile0.png");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        if(map[y][x] == 2){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile3.jpg");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        x++;
        II = x * 100;
    }
    y++;
    I = y * 100;
}
```

Screenshot http://puu.sh/iIf9r/42c3b6f4db.png

Thanks.

Comment: Is the draw method a custom one? From a quick inspection, the loops should be performing normally. On a second look, the answer below me is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I understood from your code you like to print your images in a rectangle 7x12.
If I understood well you have to reset x before each row so before the `while( x <= 12){`

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int I = 0;
int II = 0;
while(y <= 7){
    x = 0;
    while( x <= 12){
        if(map[y][x] == 0){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile1.png");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        if(map[y][x] == 1){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile0.png");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        if(map[y][x] == 2){
            Image img = new Image("res/tile3.jpg");
            img.draw(II,I);
        }
        x++;
        II = x * 100;
    }
    y++;
    I = y * 100;
}
```

**Note** to have a better performance is not needed to create a new Image each time. Create the tiles before all and reuse them.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to be that Davide's answer is correct, but I want to draw your attention to a little bit of an optimization you can make.

Currently in your loop, you are checking if your tile equals a certain value:

```
if(map[y][x] == 0)
...
if(map[y][x] == 1)
...
etc
```

This is all well and fine, until you have hundreds or thousands of tiles. All of those if statements are doing the exact thing, which is loading a tile image and drawing it. However, for speed purposes, this isn't the main issue. One of the main issues is initializing an image every single iteration when you know what the end result is. I am not familiar with `slick2d`, but you could probably do something like this:

```
// Initialize this once outside your render loop
Image[] tileImages = { 
    new Image("res/tile1.png"), 
    new Image("res/tile0.png"), 
    new Image("res/tile3.png") 
};

...

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int I = 0;
int II = 0;
while(y <= 7){
    x = 0;
    while( x <= 12){
        // This replaces a lot of unnecessary code and makes it more efficient
        tileImages[map[y][x]].draw(II, I);
        x++;
        II = x * 100;
    }
    y++;
    I = y * 100;
}
```

**Note:** I have not tested this, but the general idea is there. Also, I took Davide's original code regarding setting the value of `x = 0` and modified it with this method.